# Remove white border at the top from resizable, borderless Pyglet window

Tags: python, pyglet

I'm trying to make a borderless window in Pyglet, as I need to "customize" the window's title bar. I can apply the borderless style in the **args* `borderless=True`, but if I also use the resizable flag `resizable=True`, the window has this ugly white bar at the top. (In the Pyglet docs they also said the style could change if the window has specific arguments).
*([Here](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/programming_guide/windowing.html?#appearance) you can find the part of the docs I've read to this topic. It says you can use borderless windows for customizing the window borders.)*
I'm running windows 10 and python 3.6-32bit
**Can in somehow change the color of this bar, or remove it completely?**

Answer (score 0):

..it says you can add your own custom border (within the window) when in borderless mode. This means you will have to make your own border and have it at the top layer. Thanks for pointing the borderless option as a workaround for pyglet to "fullscreen" across two screens on a raspberry pi 4.

```
win = pyglet.window.Window(style=pyglet.window.Window.WINDOW_STYLE_BORDERLESS,width=2048, height=600)
```

Comment: I think I did not make my problem clear enough here: You're totally right, I can make a custom window border using the borderless flag. My problem was, that I also wanted the window to be resizable and borderless windows with the `rezisable` flag set, have a really ugly border at the top, that you can't overwrite. (at least on my setup).

Comment: You can try searching pyglets github issues or contacting the author. I'm not %99 sure, but the borderless option might be overridden by the resizeable flag, as most DM's might not facilitate "grab handles" on a borderless window. Far as I can tell, borderless is a fullscreen window with a smaller/different size than your screen. As for the recoloring of the window border, you could change windows theme colors to match what you want your border to look like as a makeshift "hack". Again, best bet is to try and get an answer direct from Pyglet's author on github. Hope this helps better.